# Include the text line before the specified filter select-string or findstr

Tags: findstr, select-string

PS C:\Windows\system32> `nmap -sP 10.0.1.0/24`
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-30 13:13 Vest-Europa (sommertid)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.1
Host is up (0.12s latency).
MAC Address: 90:72:40:04:F7:85 (Apple)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.2
Host is up (0.13s latency).
MAC Address: 84:C7:EA:43:1D:27 (Sony Mobile Communications AB)

If search subnet with nmap it wold look like this.
If I filter with select-string for just apple it will respond like this:

`nmap -sP 10.0.2.0/24 | Select-String "Apple"`
MAC Address: 90:72:40:04:F7:85 (Apple)

How can i filter it to get:

Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.1
Host is up (0.12s latency).
MAC Address: 90:72:40:04:F7:85 (Apple)

Also Apple line + 2 lines before?

Answer (score 0):

`nmap -sP 10.0.2.0/24 | Select-String "Apple" -Context 2,0`

I found a solution my self. This code search for vendor and add the 2 lines before so ip is included.

Same function in bash is:

`nmap -sP 10.0.2.0/24 | grep -B 2 "Climax"`